# Fetch config values from controller

Tags: angularjs

[image]I am using angular js for my project front end. I need to load config values in controller.

I used the normal import method but it keep showing the error

Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod]

Comment: Please add more details if you could.

Answer (score 0):

config values- in sense of json in a seperate file and you want to use that file in your controller.

First you need to import file into your controller: 
import {reservedWords} from '../mask/impala-reserved-words.config';

Now you have the complete json, you can use this in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still shows error.Anyway am updated the question with error console screen.

Comment: if you are using angular 1, in index file do not forget to mention your config file.    .constant('createVariablesConfig', require('./create-variables.config'))